# rounding selected faces

Tags: mesh, uv, selection-tools

Hey I created a plane and subdivided it several times till I got a nice grid. Now I want to draw an oasis. I already rounded out the outer shape. I might want to do it several times and I rounded it by hand. Is there an automatic way? I want to repeat it for the middle area now. I will have to do it for a much bigger area soon.

Is there a way to select only the green area? I can get the selection in the UV Editor as the "sand" area is on a yellow colour and the "gras" area is on a green area. Can I get the UV Editor selection to the object editor? Is there another way?

[image: reference picture]

Comment: For the selection: I'm now seperating and joining afterwards so I can select the area with "l" afterwards. Still is there another way?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gZZKYPS8VU#t=6m

Everyone is doing it by hand. Right now I'm using two planes and layering them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the loop tool plugin, it comes along the with blender.

Just enable and have a try. You seem to have used lot of subdivision, which makes the task a little difficult.

Comment: It kinda worked. Overall nice plugin to know. I had to delete the inner part and fill it again with "f". Now I can't subdivide it:

https://i.imgur.com/5nEcxAQ.png

It's also too much vertices. I'm gonna look for another solution. Thanks tho!

Comment: New questions should be asked in a new post.

Comment: As I said, the solution is not working for me and I'm looking for another way to do it. I'm getting close myself, but I don't know if its the proper way to do it, as I'm fairly new to 3d modelling.